# Android desugaring java.time.LocalDate with safe args

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

Trying to migrate from threetenabp to using desugaring in an Android project. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring

The issue I am running into is with safe args and navigation library and having a fragment argument.

E.g

```
<argument
            android:name="lastTime"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="java.time.LocalDate"
            app:nullable="true"
            />
```

Unfortunately this generates a crash on launch of the app on lower API levels. Between API 21 and API 25 but works on API 26 and above where java.time is supported without desugaring.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.LocalDate
        at androidx.navigation.NavType.fromArgType(NavType.java:181)
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflateArgument(NavInflater.java:191)
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflateArgumentForDestination(NavInflater.java:155)
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:128)
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:141)
        at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:88)
            ... 39 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.LocalDate
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
        at androidx.navigation.NavType.fromArgType(NavType.java:169)
            ... 44 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.LocalDate" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/myfancypackagename-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.medco.myfancypackagename--1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its not `safe args plugin` issue .

> NavType denotes the type that can be used in a NavArgument.

> There are built-in NavTypes for primitive types, such as int, long, boolean, float, and strings, parcelable, and serializable classes (including Enums), as well as arrays of each supported type.

In this case you are using argument type by full name class `java.time.LocalDate` which is serializable class . And its successfully classified and initialized by returning its Object through `fromArgType` method on API 26 or higher . And we know `java.time.LocalDate` added in API 26.

But `desugaring` can not solve such `ClassNotFoundException` issue while parse your argument type to NavType through `fromArgType` on lower API  , I do not know why . But you can use the API on legacy device differently . Suppose `textView.setText(LocalDate.now().getMonth().toString());`

You can check `NavType` class to see how its skipping all scope while parsing argtype .

```
    package com.example.stackoverflow;
  import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
 import androidx.annotation.AnyRes;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.ParseException;


public abstract class NavType<T> {
    private final boolean mNullableAllowed;

    NavType(boolean nullableAllowed) {
        this.mNullableAllowed = nullableAllowed;
    }


    public boolean isNullableAllowed() {
        return mNullableAllowed;
    }


    public abstract void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable T value);

    @Nullable
    public abstract T get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key);


    @NonNull
    public abstract T parseValue(@NonNull String value);

    @NonNull
    T parseAndPut(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @NonNull String value) {
        T parsedValue = parseValue(value);
        put(bundle, key, parsedValue);
        return parsedValue;
    }
   
    @NonNull
    public abstract String getName();

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @NonNull
    public static NavType<?> fromArgType(@Nullable String type, @Nullable String packageName) {
        if (IntType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return IntType;
        } else if (IntArrayType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return IntArrayType;
        } else if (LongType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return LongType;
        } else if (LongArrayType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return LongArrayType;
        } else if (BoolType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return BoolType;
        } else if (BoolArrayType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return BoolArrayType;
        } else if (StringType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return StringType;
        } else if (StringArrayType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return StringArrayType;
        } else if (FloatType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return FloatType;
        } else if (FloatArrayType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return FloatArrayType;
        } else if (ReferenceType.getName().equals(type)) {
            return ReferenceType;
        } else if (type != null && !type.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                String className;
                if (type.startsWith(".") && packageName != null) {
                    className = packageName + type;
                } else {
                    className = type;
                }

                if (type.endsWith("[]")) {
                    className = className.substring(0, className.length() - 2);
                    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
                    if (Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                        return new ParcelableArrayType(clazz);
                    } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                        return new SerializableArrayType(clazz);
                    }
                } else {
                    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
                    if (Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                        return new ParcelableType(clazz);
                    } else if (Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                        return new EnumType(clazz);
                    } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                        return new SerializableType(clazz);
                    }
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(className + " is not Serializable or "
                        + "Parcelable.");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return StringType;
    }

    @NonNull
    static NavType inferFromValue(@NonNull String value) {
        //because we allow Long literals without the L suffix at runtime,
        //the order of IntType and LongType parsing has to be reversed compared to Safe Args
        try {
            IntType.parseValue(value);
            return IntType;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //ignored, proceed to check next type
        }
        try {
            LongType.parseValue(value);
            return LongType;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //ignored, proceed to check next type
        }

        try {
            FloatType.parseValue(value);
            return FloatType;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //ignored, proceed to check next type
        }

        try {
            BoolType.parseValue(value);
            return BoolType;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //ignored, proceed to check next type
        }

        return StringType;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @NonNull
    static NavType inferFromValueType(@Nullable Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            return IntType;
        } else if (value instanceof int[]) {
            return IntArrayType;
        } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            return LongType;
        } else if (value instanceof long[]) {
            return LongArrayType;
        } else if (value instanceof Float) {
            return FloatType;
        } else if (value instanceof float[]) {
            return FloatArrayType;
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            return BoolType;
        } else if (value instanceof boolean[]) {
            return BoolArrayType;
        } else if (value instanceof String || value == null) {
            return StringType;
        } else if (value instanceof String[]) {
            return StringArrayType;
        } else if (value.getClass().isArray()
                && Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass().getComponentType())) {
            return new ParcelableArrayType(value.getClass().getComponentType());
        } else if (value.getClass().isArray()
                && Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass().getComponentType())) {
            return new SerializableArrayType(value.getClass().getComponentType());
        } else if (value instanceof Parcelable) {
            return new ParcelableType(value.getClass());
        } else if (value instanceof Enum) {
            return new EnumType(value.getClass());
        } else if (value instanceof Serializable) {
            return new SerializableType(value.getClass());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object of type " + value.getClass().getName()
                    + " is not supported for navigation arguments.");
        }
    }
  
    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<Integer> IntType = new NavType<Integer>(false) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @NonNull Integer value) {
            bundle.putInt(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (Integer) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Integer parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            if (value.startsWith("0x")) {
                return Integer.parseInt(value.substring(2), 16);
            } else {
                return Integer.parseInt(value);
            }
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "integer";
        }
    };
    
    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<Integer> ReferenceType = new NavType<Integer>(false) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key,
                        @NonNull @AnyRes Integer value) {
            bundle.putInt(key, value);
        }

        @AnyRes
        @Override
        public Integer get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (Integer) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Integer parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "References don't support parsing string values.");
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "reference";
        }
    };
   
    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<int[]> IntArrayType = new NavType<int[]>(true) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable int[] value) {
            bundle.putIntArray(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public int[] get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (int[]) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public int[] parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays don't support default values.");
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "integer[]";
        }
    };
 
    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<Long> LongType = new NavType<Long>(false) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @NonNull Long value) {
            bundle.putLong(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public Long get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (Long) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Long parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            //At runtime the L suffix is optional, contrary to the Safe Args plugin.
            //This is in order to be able to parse long numbers passed as deep link URL parameters
            if (value.endsWith("L")) {
                value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
            }
            if (value.startsWith("0x")) {
                return Long.parseLong(value.substring(2), 16);
            } else {
                return Long.parseLong(value);
            }
        }    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "long";
        }
    };
   
    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<long[]> LongArrayType = new NavType<long[]>(true) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable long[] value) {
            bundle.putLongArray(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public long[] get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (long[]) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public long[] parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays don't support default values.");
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "long[]";
        }
    };
    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<Float> FloatType = new NavType<Float>(false) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @NonNull Float value) {
            bundle.putFloat(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public Float get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (Float) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Float parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            return Float.parseFloat(value);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "float";
        }
    };
 
    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<float[]> FloatArrayType = new NavType<float[]>(true) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable float[] value) {
            bundle.putFloatArray(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public float[] get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (float[]) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public float[] parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays don't support default values.");
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "float[]";
        }
    };


    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<Boolean> BoolType = new NavType<Boolean>(false) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @NonNull Boolean value) {
            bundle.putBoolean(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (Boolean) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Boolean parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            if ("true".equals(value)) {
                return true;
            } else if ("false".equals(value)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "A boolean NavType only accepts \"true\" or \"false\" values.");
            }
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "boolean";
        }
    };


    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<boolean[]> BoolArrayType = new NavType<boolean[]>(true) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable boolean[] value) {
            bundle.putBooleanArray(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean[] get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (boolean[]) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public boolean[] parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays don't support default values.");
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "boolean[]";
        }
    };

    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<String> StringType = new NavType<String>(true) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable String value) {
            bundle.putString(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public String get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (String) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            return value;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "string";
        }
    };
  
    @NonNull
    public static final NavType<String[]> StringArrayType = new NavType<String[]>(true) {
        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable String[] value) {
            bundle.putStringArray(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public String[] get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (String[]) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String[] parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays don't support default values.");
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "string[]";
        }
    };

    public static final class ParcelableType<D> extends NavType<D> {
        @NonNull
        private final Class<D> mType;
        public ParcelableType(@NonNull Class<D> type) {
            super(true);
            if (!Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)
                    && !Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        type + " does not implement Parcelable or Serializable.");
            }
            this.mType = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable D value) {
            mType.cast(value);
            if (value == null || value instanceof Parcelable) {
                bundle.putParcelable(key, (Parcelable) value);
            } else if (value instanceof Serializable) {
                bundle.putSerializable(key, (Serializable) value);
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        @Nullable
        public D get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (D) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public D parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parcelables don't support default values.");
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public String getName() {
            return mType.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            ParcelableType<?> that = (ParcelableType<?>) o;

            return mType.equals(that.mType);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return mType.hashCode();
        }
    }


    public static final class ParcelableArrayType<D extends Parcelable> extends NavType<D[]> {
        @NonNull
        private final Class<D[]> mArrayType;

        /**
         * Constructs a NavType that supports arrays of a given Parcelable type.
         * @param type class that is a subtype of Parcelable
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public ParcelableArrayType(@NonNull Class<D> type) {
            super(true);
            if (!Parcelable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        type + " does not implement Parcelable.");
            }

            Class<D[]> arrayType;
            try {
                arrayType = (Class<D[]>) Class.forName("[L" + type.getName() + ";");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); //should never happen
            }
            this.mArrayType = arrayType;
        }

        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable D[] value) {
            mArrayType.cast(value);
            bundle.putParcelableArray(key, value);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        @Nullable
        public D[] get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (D[]) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public D[] parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays don't support default values.");
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public String getName() {
            return mArrayType.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            ParcelableArrayType<?> that = (ParcelableArrayType<?>) o;

            return mArrayType.equals(that.mArrayType);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return mArrayType.hashCode();
        }
    }

    public static class SerializableType<D extends Serializable> extends NavType<D> {
        @NonNull
        private final Class<D> mType;

        /**
         * Constructs a NavType that supports a given Serializable type.
         * @param type class that is a subtype of Serializable
         */
        public SerializableType(@NonNull Class<D> type) {
            super(true);
            if (!Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        type + " does not implement Serializable.");
            }
            if (type.isEnum()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        type + " is an Enum. You should use EnumType instead.");
            }
            this.mType = type;
        }

        SerializableType(boolean nullableAllowed, @NonNull Class<D> type) {
            super(nullableAllowed);
            if (!Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        type + " does not implement Serializable.");
            }
            this.mType = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable D value) {
            mType.cast(value);
            bundle.putSerializable(key, value);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        @Nullable
        public D get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (D) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public D parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Serializables don't support default values.");
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public String getName() {
            return mType.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof SerializableType)) return false;

            SerializableType<?> that = (SerializableType<?>) o;

            return mType.equals(that.mType);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return mType.hashCode();
        }
    }
    public static final class EnumType<D extends Enum> extends SerializableType<D> {
        @NonNull
        private final Class<D> mType;

        /**
         * Constructs a NavType that supports a given Enum type.
         * @param type class that is an Enum
         */
        public EnumType(@NonNull Class<D> type) {
            super(false, type);
            if (!type.isEnum()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        type + " is not an Enum type.");
            }
            mType = type;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public D parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            for (Object constant : mType.getEnumConstants()) {
                if (((Enum) constant).name().equals(value)) {
                    return (D) constant;
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enum value " + value + " not found for type "
                    + mType.getName() + ".");
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public String getName() {
            return mType.getName();
        }
    }


    public static final class SerializableArrayType<D extends Serializable> extends NavType<D[]> {
        @NonNull
        private final Class<D[]> mArrayType;

        /**
         * Constructs a NavType that supports arrays of a given Serializable type.
         * @param type class that is a subtype of Serializable
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public SerializableArrayType(@NonNull Class<D> type) {
            super(true);
            if (!Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        type + " does not implement Serializable.");
            }

            Class<D[]> arrayType;
            try {
                arrayType = (Class<D[]>) Class.forName("[L" + type.getName() + ";");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); //should never happen
            }
            this.mArrayType = arrayType;
        }

        @Override
        public void put(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key, @Nullable D[] value) {
            mArrayType.cast(value);
            bundle.putSerializable(key, value);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        @Nullable
        public D[] get(@NonNull Bundle bundle, @NonNull String key) {
            return (D[]) bundle.get(key);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public D[] parseValue(@NonNull String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Arrays don't support default values.");
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public String getName() {
            return mArrayType.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            SerializableArrayType<?> that = (SerializableArrayType<?>) o;

            return mArrayType.equals(that.mArrayType);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return mArrayType.hashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage from another activity -

```
NavType.fromArgType("java.time.LocalDate","java.time");
```

You would see same error on lower API though you enabled `desugaring`  or D8 compiled 8+ APIs  ,

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the link to the issue tracker. Looks like the plugin has some issue and currently the only way is to wrap the LocalDate in a non desugared object or use a different representation of LocalDate (e.g long or string)

Hopefully it will be fixed soon and we all can use java.time.LocalDate with safe args plugin.

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/160257645

Answer (score -1):

SafeArgs can only be things that can be put inside a bundle.
That being the value types (int, double, Boolean, etc) and Serializables and Parcelables.

As LocalDate isn't any of these, you'll have to find a way to convert the LocalDate, then covert it back.

I think Date is Parcelable, or you can use the string form.

Comment: `java.time.LocalDate` is Serializable so it should be working. `public final class LocalDate
        implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, ChronoLocalDate, Serializable {`  The issue here is the desugaring and for some reason it does not happen for it when it is generated by safeargs.